# annotation_custom behaves unexpectedly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble adding some curved arrows to a plot. The plot combines a `geom_polygon()`...

```
require(rworldmap)    
g <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = getMap(resolution = 'low'),
                        aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
```

...with lots of `geom_point()`s from different data sources. e.g.:

```
data1 <- c(0, 52)
g + geom_point(aes(data1[1], data1[2]), size = 5, color = 'red')
```

So far, so good. The specific problem I'm having is with regards to adding a `curveGrob()` as `annotation_custom()`. Here's a simple curve:

```
myCurve<-curveGrob(0, 0, 1, 1, default.units = "npc",
                   curvature = 0.3, angle = 90, ncp = 20, shape = 1,
                   square = FALSE, squareShape = 1,
                   inflect = FALSE, arrow = arrow(), open = TRUE,
                   debug = FALSE,
                   name = NULL, gp = gpar(), vp = NULL)
```

And here's some simplified code demonstrating my problem. This bit works as expected.

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(11:20))
base <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
base + annotation_custom(grob = myCurve)
```

But when the `ggplot()` command is empty (as is necessary because different geoms are using different data, the `annotation_custom()` fails to draw

```
base <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = data, aes(x, y))
base + annotation_custom(grob = myCurve)
```

Comment: More generally, is it bad practice to use different data sources for each geom layer? If so, how can this be avoided?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad practice to use multiple datasets for layers, but they must share coordinate systems and you need to establish the limits of your plot area, so a blank `ggplot()` will fail to provide the proper framework.

Comment: You have a false premise: *[empty `ggplot(...)` command] is necessary because different geoms are using different data*. This is not true. You cna specify a default dataset in the `ggplot(...)` call and then override it locally with the `data=...` argument in specific `geom_*` calls.

Comment: Humm, I did try overriding the default with `data=`, but it threw an error along the lines of 'object 'group' does not exist'. But it works fine with the simplified code above, so perhaps there's a deeper issue with my coding. I'll have a play tomorrow. Cheers